# Python - Help needed with parsing file. Is there a way to ignore EOF chars?

Tags: python, binary, ascii, non-ascii-characters, fileparsing

I have a binary file that I am trying to extract strings from and I am having quite the time doing so. :(

My current strategy is to read in the file using Python (using  one of the following functions: read(), readline(), or readlines()). Next, I parse through the line (char by char) and look for the special character 'ô', which in **most cases** directly follows the strings I want! Lastly, I parse backwards from the special char recording all chars that I have identified as being "valid."

At the end of the day, I want the front time stamp and the next 3 strings within the line.

Results:

In the input example line #1 the "read" functions won't read through the entire line (shown in the output image). I believe this is because the function is interpreting the binary as an EOF char and then it stops reading on.

In line #2 of the example, there are times in which the "special char" shows up, however it is not after a string I want to extract. :(

Is there a better way to parse this data?  If not, is there way to solve issue seen in example line #1?

Examples of input data and the resulting output data when I just print the lines as read. As you can see, it does not read through the entire line when using `readlines()`
[image: Examples of input data and the resulting output data when I just print the lines as read. As you can see, it does not read through the entire line when using readlines()]

My string extraction algorithm, which is not very robust.
[image: My string extraction algorithm, which is not very robust.]

FYI, efficiency is not necessarily import.

Comment: By posting your code as a screenshot image, you're making it much harder for us to help you.

Comment: There's no such thing as an EOF character, EOF is just the condition of reaching the end of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Why use Python. Use strings and pipe it through head, eg

```
    strings /bin/ls | head -3
```

and see what you get. You can get a strings for Windows too.

Comment: This seems to be what I am looking for. I download strings2 for windows and gave it a shot and it seems to working well! Here is the output:
<br/>
`41080,
1-Hello Comapany Here
?= Carpenter
202-Carpenter House
Personxyz
<br/>

401058,
owner of area
LLC company names
213-Ingledue East
names`<br/>
<br/>
As you can, it only messed up 1 time. This something I think I can clean up in python by filtering some chars that I know will not be used.
<br/>
Thank you for the suggestion @Jorgen.

Comment: Sorry I am new to this :/

This seems to be what I am looking for. I download strings2 for windows and gave it a shot and it seems to working well! Here is the output:  
`41080,
1-Hello Comapany Here
?= Carpenter
202-Carpenter House
Personxyz  

401058,
owner of area
LLC company names
213-Ingledue East
names`  
As you can, it only messed up 1 time. This something I think I can clean up in python by filtering some chars that I know will not be used.  
Thank you for the suggestion @Jorgen.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is binary, don't read it as text. Read it as the binary data it is, and then attempt to find strings embedded in the binary data.

```
with open("example.tp", "b") as f:
    data = f.read() # produces a bytes object in python 3
```

Now split your data based on the terminal character

```
parts = data.split(b'\xf4') # f4 is hex code for your o character in latin-1
```

Now extract the string from each part as best you can:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

special_chars = '-()&, '
desired_chars = bytes(ascii_letters + digits + special_chars, encoding="ascii")

data = b'0,123\xf4NOPE#Hello world\xf4ignored' # sample data

parts = data.split(b'\xf4')

strings = []
for p in parts[:-1]: # ignore last part as it is never followed by the split char
    reversed_bytes = p[::-1]
    # extract the string
    for i, byte in enumerate(reversed_bytes):
        if byte not in desired_chars:
            chunk = reversed_bytes[:i]
            break
    else:
        chunk = reversed_bytes # all chars were valid
    bytes_ = chunk[::-1]
    bytes_ = bytes_.replace(b',', b'')
    strings.append(bytes_.decode("ascii")) # turn into a str
    # use ascii codec as there should be no non-ascii bytes in your string

print(strings) # prints ['0123', 'Hello world']
```